# Importing SQLite As A Dependency To A Swift Framework, And Using That Framework

Tags: swift, xcode, carthage

I have a Swift framework that wraps SQLite. It targets iOS, macOS, and tvOS. To achieve this, the individual platforms reference another target that is a simple modulemap to the SQLite header and library.

I then set up Carthage to import this library. For Xcode 7 / Swift 2.2 and Xcode 8 / Swift 2.3, this was working correctly. For Xcode 8 / Swift 3, I get the following at run time:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/SQLite.framework/SQLite
  Referenced from: /Users/*****/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/89E1BBC9-E15D-41F5-A444-7EAD878FFB97/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/075FE984-2C88-44D8-8481-C269FDFAF05A/***********.app/Frameworks/Structure.framework/Structure
  Reason: image not found
```

[The link to the library can be found here](https://github.com/stack/Structure/tree/2.0). The Swift 3 branch is `2.0`.

Any thoughts as to what needs to change? Or is this a bug in the toolchain?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you get this solved?